# write a single image file from any frame of a video file using JMF(java media framework) shows javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player

Tags: java, jmf

this is my code to get image from video using JMF(java media framework):

```
public class ImageCaptureFromVideo {
    private static final String outputFilePrefix = "C:/Pics/";

    public static void main(String ar[]) {

        try
        {

            URL url=new File("C:/Pics/daddy_baby.mp4").toURI().oURL();

            MediaLocator mediaLocator = new MediaLocator(url);

//Player p =Manager.createRealizedPlayer(newURL("file:///C:/Pics/daddy_baby.mp4"));

            Player p = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mediaLocator);

            FramePositioningControl fpc = (FramePositioningControl)

            p.getControl("javax.media.control.FramePositioningControl");

            FrameGrabbingControl fg =(FrameGrabbingControl)p.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");

            p.prefetch();

            fpc.seek(100);

            Buffer buf = fg.grabFrame();

            VideoFormat vf = (VideoFormat) buf.getFormat();

            BufferToImage bufferToImage = new BufferToImage(vf);

            Image im = bufferToImage.createImage(buf);

            BufferedImage formatImg = new BufferedImage(360, 360, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

            dumpImageToFile(formatImg);

            Graphics g = formatImg.getGraphics();

            g.drawImage(im, 0, 0, 360, 360, null);

            g.dispose();

        }

        catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("exception i " + e);

        }

    }

    private static String dumpImageToFile(BufferedImage image) {

        try

        {

            String outputFilename = outputFilePrefix + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";

            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(outputFilename));

            return outputFilename;

        }

        catch (IOException e)

        {

            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;

        }
    }

}
```

but it shows :

> javax.media.NoPlayerException: Cannot find a Player for :file:/C:/Pics/daddy_baby.mp4

at `Player p = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mediaLocator);`

Comment: please format your code correctlly

Comment: Show me the part of the {KMF supported formats](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/formats-138492.html) that lists MP4?